# passport-apple Node.js login error - Failed to obtain access token

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am a junior engineer working in a start-up in Seoul, Korea.
In the current project, I am trying to use the passport module to develop apple login.
I have already finished developing google social login, but I faced some problems while trying to do the same with apple.

The problem is that I get an error that states : "Failed to obtain access token".

I got really confused that you have to use the POST method in order to get the profile info from apple.

Can someone please help me?? Thanks in advance!

IT would be wonderful if I could success. Thanks again

The main problem I am expecting is that
passport.authenticate('apple') calls the function which handles passport module for google that I have already developed.

1. I send the redirect url to Frontend, in order to open the browser in my application.

```
ROUTER.get('/apple/login', async function (req, res) {
  const result = { status: 'N' };
  const config = {
    client_id: APPLE_AUTH.CLIENT_ID, // This is the service ID we created.
    redirect_uri: APPLE_AUTH.REDIRECT_URI, // As registered along with our service ID
    response_type: 'code id_token',
    // state: 'origin:web', // Any string of your choice that you may use for some logic. It's optional and you may omit it.
    scope: 'name email', // To tell apple we want the user name and emails fields in the response it sends us.
    response_mode: 'form_post',
    m: 11,
    v: '1.5.4',
  };

  const queryString = Object.entries(config)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');

  const redirectUrl = `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?${queryString}`;
  result['redirectUrl'] = redirectUrl;
  result['status'] = 'Y';
  res.json(result);
});
```

2. I get the url, and open the browser

```
async openAppleSignIn() {
    const result = await this.authService.postAppleLogin();
    // await this.authService.postAppleLogin();
    if (result.data.status === 'Y') {
      const { redirectUrl } = result.data;
      console.log(redirectUrl);
      if (this.deviceInfo.platform !== 'web') {
        // this.browserService.openBrowser(redirectUrl);
        window.open(redirectUrl, '_self');
        console.log('enter');
      } else {
        const timer = setInterval(async () => {
          if (this.newWindowForLogin.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);
          }
        }, 500);
        const isChrome = this.commonService.checkBrowserIsChrome();
        if (!this.newWindowForLogin || isChrome) {
          // this.newWindowForLogin = window.open();
          window.open(redirectUrl);
        }
        // this.newWindowForLogin.location.href = redirectUrl;
      }
    } else {
    }
```

3. Apple strategy

```
const passport = require('passport');
// var AppleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
var AppleStrategy = require('passport-apple').Strategy;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// var fs = require('fs');

const APPLE_AUTH = require('../../../config/secret_key').get('APPLE_AUTH');
const UserModelService = require('../../api/user/model/user_model_service');

// const applePrivateKey = fs.readFileSync('config/AuthKey_Y8BG5JY7P3.p8');

// console.log(applePrivateKey);

module.exports = () => {
  passport.use(
    'apple',
    new AppleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: APPLE_AUTH.CLIENT_ID,
        teamID: APPLE_AUTH.TEAM_ID,
        callbackURL: APPLE_AUTH.LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL,
        keyID: APPLE_AUTH.KEY_ID,
        privateKeyLocation: 'config/AuthKey_Y8BG5JY7P3.p8',
        privateKeyString: APPLE_AUTH.privateKey,
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, idToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
          // console.log(profile._json.email);
          // const socialLoginEmail = req.user.emails[0].value;
          // console.log(email);
          //화면에서 백으로
          // console.log(profile._json.email);
          // const user = await UserModelService.getUser(profile._json.email);
          // console.log(user);
          console.log('jwt', jwt.decode(idToken));
          console.log('strategy', req);
          done(null, idToken);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          // done(error);
        }
      },
    ),
  );
};
```

4. index.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const apple = require('./apple_auth');
const google = require('./google_auth');

module.exports = () => {
  apple();
  google();
};
```

5.Then, I intended to get the results in callback

```
ROUTER.post(
  '/apple/callback',
  passport.authenticate('apple', { failureRedirect: '/', session: false }),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(req);
    } catch (err) {}
  },
);
```

- I customized the passport-apple usage into this way, not following the instructions in the passport docs, because the way they listed in the official document did not work for my code.

Thanks again, and I hope to find an answer in stack overflow!!

Comment: Could you please edit you question and add snippet with your code?

Comment: I added in the codes ! would you please take a look at it? @DamianSowiński